# Существование компонента

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток! Прошу, подскажите как проверить существование компонента на форме(язык c#). Вроде как простая задача, а никак не получается. 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал искать контрол рекурсивно, иначе как только Вы положите контрол во вложенный контейнер, Ваша схема сломается.

```
bool Find(Control resContainer, ControlCollection controls)
{
  if (controls.Contains(resContainer))
    return true;

  foreach (var control in controls)
  {
    if (this.Find(resContainer, control.Controls))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.Controls.Contains( someBtn )) {
    // TO DO
}
// или так

if (this.Controls.ContainsKey( "someBtn" )) {
   // TO DO:
}
```

[Подробней здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx)

Comment: Не успел ))

Answer (score 0):

Уже сам раздуплился.

```
this.Controls.Contains(resContainer)
```

Прописывать внутри формы или указывать ее. resContainer - сам элемент. Возвращает true, если элемент существует и false – при не осуществлении его инициализации.